# Is GNOME used in Ubuntu?

Tags: gnome

I am a first-time Linux user and I started learning about Linux recently. I understand GNOME is a GUI used in most Linux systems. Does Ubuntu use GNOME or any similar desktop GUI?

Answer (score 1):

By default, Ubuntu uses Unity. GNOME is optional and can be installed using:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Then on LightDM (the login manager), select GNOME.

[image: GNOME login]

Comment: I suggest installing `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` instead of  `gnome`